# What directory set for build tomcat openshift v3 app?

Tags: java, build, openshift, tomcat8

i deploy my project with github to openshift v3 then build and have error "Invalid context directory"

what directory is correct?, tell me please!

Comment: this is folder where placed you src folder

Answer (score 0):

The context directory (contextDir) is the path within your git repo to use as the working directory. Set it to an empty value to use the root directory, or add a path "my/path" to set an alternate working directory.

If you're using the Tomcat 8 example template in OpenShift Online, the example is setup to use [this git repo](https://github.com/jboss-openshift/openshift-quickstarts) which contains multiple examples, so it's necessary to set the context directory for the build to a specific example (in this case, it's set to `tomcat-websocket-chat`). If you change the git repo the template references, you'll probably want to change the context directory (or not use the template). You're probably getting the error trying to use a git repo that doesn't have a `tomcat-websocket-chat` directory.

See build inputs: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#how-build-inputs-work